# Finding data in multiple tables and replacing them?

Tags: mysql

I want to find specific IDs in my mysql database whose values contain specific text.  There are 2 tables where page IDs and data are stored.  What query do I run to replace text that is found?

MY guess is this:

`SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE ID='1,2,3' REPLACE (Text1, Text1, text5)`

Replace every occurrence of "Text1" with "text5" in both tables only for those IDs.

Comment: You are looking for `update`. Please take a SQL tutorial. This is very basic.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @juergend - ok, if it's so basic, why don't you provide me with the right query to use?  `UPDATE value='text5' WHERE ID=1,2,3 FROM table1, table2` but where would I put the original text at?  the query would not know what to replace.

Comment: The query I have now is: `UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE("text1","text1","text2") WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3');` problem is, that query took an entire body of content and replaced it with the new text.  I'll have to do a rollback.  good thing it affected only a few IDs.

Comment: Because a) SO doesn't encourage spoonfeeding, and b) the question is so poor, we may have misunderstood the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

> for two tables **Book** and **Orders**

```
UPDATE Books, Orders
SET Orders.Quantity=Orders.Quantity+5,   ---> // updated value
Books.InStock=Books.InStock-5           ----> //updated value
WHERE Books.BookID=Orders.BookID
 AND Orders.OrderID = 1234;
```

Comment: so "5" is the new value to replace "1234"?

Comment: No, in cureent query `quantity+5` is implementing for changing value to 5 you can write 5 at `Orders.Quantity=5` , `Books.InStock=5`